# Math algorithm for n amount points in objective-c

Tags: ios, trilateration

I need some information about the Answer on an earlier [**Question**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40660/trilateration-algorithm-for-n-amount-of-points).

I need this calculation for an iOS App. I have three  points with different Circles.
I understand the problem and your solution. But i have no idea how the function self works.
Do you have an idea which libary can help me to solve this problem (C C++)
I also looked at google. But i'm not really sure which lib can do this.

I need this for objective c. Also google had no solution for me.

Maybe you have me some Resources or a Mathematic description for me.
It would help me really when you have some Informations for me.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403282/non-linear-least-squares-optimization-library-for-c

Comment: Hey Thank you, i already found this link. And i think i will use this lib.

http://www.alglib.net/optimization/

But im not sure which function is the best for me or which function should i use. I don't know the right way to get a solution.